# Table with first cell wider than the rest

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got a `table` with `table-layout: fixed;` because I want all cells to be the same width even if empty, but I cant find a way to make the first one wider so that the text will fit, any ideas how to make this work?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RtXSh/231/)

HTML

```
<div class="prTableContainerScroll">
    <table id="squatTable" class="prTable">
        <tr class="prTableHeader">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>                 
        </tr>
        <tr class="prTableRow">
            <td class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Wider to fit</td>
            <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td> <!-- Space --> 
            <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">50</td>
            <td class="prTableCell">60</td>
            <td class="prTableCell"></td>
            <td class="prTableCell">80</td>
            <td class="prTableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="prTableRow">
            <td class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Wider to fit 1</td>
            <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td> <!-- Space -->
            <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">50</td>
            <td class="prTableCell"></td>
            <td class="prTableCell">70</td>
            <td class="prTableCell">80</td>
            <td class="prTableCell"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.prTableContainerScroll {
    width: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.prTable {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 400px;
}

.prTableCell {
  padding: 7px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  cursor: default;
}

.prExerVariNameTD {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1!important;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `colspan` to say that column should take the width of `x` columns:

```css
.prTableContainerScroll {
    width: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.prTable {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 400px;
}

.prTableCell {
  padding: 7px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  cursor: default;
}

.prExerVariNameTD {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1!important;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}



// Just color stuff. 
.prTableCell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.prTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}

.prTableRow:hover .prTableCell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.prTableRow:hover .prTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="prTableContainerScroll">
<table id="squatTable" class="prTable">
  <tr class="prTableHeader">
    <th colspan="4"></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>                 
  </tr>
  <tr class="prTableRow">
    <td colspan="4" class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Wider to fit</td>
    <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td> <!-- Space --> 
    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">50</td>
    <td class="prTableCell">60</td>
    <td class="prTableCell"></td>
    <td class="prTableCell">80</td>
    <td class="prTableCell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="prTableRow">
    <td colspan="4" class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Wider to fit 1</td>
    <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td> <!-- Space -->
    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">50</td>
    <td class="prTableCell"></td>
    <td class="prTableCell">70</td>
    <td class="prTableCell">80</td>
    <td class="prTableCell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with colspan , or you have to increase the table width, or u have to decrease the wodth of verticalSpcaes Cell .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the width of first column and keep the rest same size, just give the first `th` or first `td` some width:

```
#squatTable td:first-child {
     width: 100px;
}
```

**Or**, if you want all the columns to have same size (including the first column) and you want the text to go next line if too long, simply remove this line:

```
.prTableContainerScroll {
    width: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    /*white-space: nowrap; <<<< comment out this line */
}
```